# How to get the day of the week using enumeration

Tags: java, date, datetime-format, encapsulation, dayofweek

I already have the code but the the day of the week doesn't match up.
The second input is a bit off. This is julian day formula i think.

```
enum Day {
 MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI, SAT, SUN;
}
  public Day dayOfTheWeek() {
  
  int D = day, M = month, Y = year, A, B, C, intindex;
  
  double E = 0, F = 0, JD = 0, num1, num2;
  
  if((M == 1 || M == 2)) {
    Y--;
    M += 12;
  }
  
  A = Y / 100;
  B = A / 4;
  C = 2 - A + B;
  E = 365.25 * (Y + 4716);
  F = 30.6001 * (M + 1);
  JD = (C + D + E + F) - 1524.5;
  num1 = JD % 7;
  intindex = (int) num1;
  num2 = num1 - intindex;
  
  if(num2 + 0.1 >= 1) {
    intindex++;
  }
  
  return Day.values()[intindex];
  
  }
```

***input:***

```
1/1/1972
20/8/1980
```

***Output:***

```
1/1/1972
SAT
20/8/1980
TUE
```

***Expected output:***

```
1/1/1972
SAT
20/8/1980
WED
```

***EDIT:*** the code works fine now. Just need to make the enum Day from MON to SUN not SUN to MON.

Comment: Is this you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65177045/can-someone-teach-me-where-to-start-with-this-method ?

Comment: No, I think he is also learning at codechum where i use to learn encapsulation @fluffy

Comment: You should mention when posting for homework/learning rather than for practical solution.

Comment: sorry, I'll do that next time. thank you for recomending @Basil Bourque

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you do it using the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = getDay("1/1/1972");
        System.out.println(dayOfWeek);
        System.out.println(dayOfWeek.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH));
        System.out.println(dayOfWeek.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.ENGLISH));
    }

    static DayOfWeek getDay(String dateString) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/M/uuuu");
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateString, dtf);
        return date.getDayOfWeek();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
SATURDAY
Saturday
Sat
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API at **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: I suspect the Question was a programming homework assignment, not a practical question.

Answer (score 1):

I got it. just need to arrage the enum from MON to SUN not SUN to MON.